# Shell - Execute imagemagic for all files in directory and store result

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick

I need to execute next **imagemagick** command

```
convert some_image.jpeg logo: -fuzz 0% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:
```

for all `jpeg` images inside some directory. The command above will return the percentage number (like 95.922983.4128). I need to compare that number to some threshold (say 98%) and if the percentage is greater than the threshold - move file to another directory.

Currently what I have is:

```
for filename in /writeData/TAX1040/*.jpeg; do
    white=$(convert $(filename) logo: -fuzz 0% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]")
    echo -n "$white"
done
```

And I have a `missing an image filename` error.

Thanks to @oliv I have a working script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p /writeData/TAX1040/blank

for filename in /writeData/TAX1040/*.jpeg; do
    white=`convert $filename logo: -fuzz 0% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]" info:`

    p=${white:0:2}

    if [ "$p" -ge 98 ]; then
        echo "Percentage of white in file $filename is $p"
        echo "Moving file $filename to blank directory"
        mv "$filename" /writeData/TAX1040/blank
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file must be used with `"$filename"` instead of `$(filename)` that actually executes the command `filename` (which is likely to fail).

Assuming that you `convert` command line is correct, you can then perform your check on the value like this:

```
threshold=98
for filename in /writeData/TAX1040/*.jpeg; do
  white=$(convert "$filename" logo: -fuzz 0% -negate -threshold 0 -negate -format "%[fx:100*mean]")
  if(( white > threshold )); then
     mv "$filename" /to/another/path
done
```

Note that in a arithmetic expression `((...))` you don't need to use the `$` for the expansion.